# Working on some Javascript, worked before, changed it, Ctrl+Z'ed it back, stopped working

Tags: javascript, html

The code was working before, changed some things in the code and then Ctrl+Z'ed it back to its original state, and then it stopped working. I'm fairly sure that I took it back to its original state. Help me Stackoverflow, you're my only hope.

I started with some inputs:

```
<div class="inputField_1">
<input id="urlInput" type="text"/>
<br>
<input type="submit" onclick="getURL()"></input>
</div>
```

Then I wrote up the code:

```
var urlInput = $("#urlInput").val();

var img = new Image();
img.src = urlInput

var width = img.width;
var height = img.height;

function getURL() {
    $(".aboutTitleWrap").append("<p>This image has: " + width * height + " pixels</p>");
};
```

The purpose is for the user to input an image URL, the Javascript to get the images width and height, and then multiply them to get the number of pixels. Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Edit: I suppose it's important to note, the output I'm getting is "This image has: 0 pixels"

Edit2: Sorry guys, I'm new, and thus complete shit at Javascript. In any case, thanks for the help.

Comment: you need to wait for the image to load before height/width properties reflect any real dimensions. Setting the src values just starts the download. you can use the onload event to see when you can check the images dimensions.

Comment: Ctrl-Z didn't break your code.

Comment: I don't get what `$(".abouTitleWrap")` represents since there is no class named like that ?

Comment: $(".abouTitleWrap") is a reference to another part of the page. It's just telling it where to append the output.

Comment: Just put the `width` and `height` variable assignments inside the `getURL()` function. Mostly likely by the time they click, the image will be loaded. You can also test the image's `.complete` property to see if it has downloaded yet.

Comment: It's not a bad question. I just think people are getting a little distracted by red herrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of things very very wrong.
I made you a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y9zbup64/5/).

First: Your html was wrong. I fixed it.

```
<div class="inputField_1">
    <input id="urlInput" type="text"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" id="button" />
</div>
<span class="aboutTitleWrap"></span>
```

Second: Always separate Logic and Layout. Put the click-handler in the JavaScript.

Third: JavaScript will not wait until the image is loaded. So we need an onload handler to fire, when the image is ready. Thx to six fingered man for pointing that out.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = $("#urlInput").val();
    img.onload = function(){
         $(".aboutTitleWrap").html("<p>This image has: " + img.width*img.height + " pixels</p>");
    }
});
```

Comment: This has the same problem too. If it's working for the OP, then it's likely that the image was cached. But you're going to load a new image when a click happens, which means its `width` and `height` won't be available.

Comment: you are right... didn't think of that. Now it will work.

Comment: I have a feeling that some browsers may not invoke the `onload` handler if the image was cached. Not sure though. If that's the case, he could check `if (img.complete) {` and then either bind the handler or execute the code. ...but +1 anyway for the fix. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Correct your input, `</input>` doesn't exists:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="getURL()">
```

You can do what you want like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="inputField_1">
    <input id="urlInput" type="text"/><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submitUrl"/>
</div>

<div class="aboutTitleWrap"></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$("#submitUrl").on("click", function(){
    var urlInput = $("#urlInput").val();
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = urlInput

    var width = img.width;
    var height = img.height;
    $(".aboutTitleWrap").append("<p>This image has: " + width*height + " pixels</p>");
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/8m55r3xq/1/

Comment: That wouldn't break anything.

Comment: While this is true, it most likely is not the reason for the problem, as it normally will just be ignored.

Comment: `+ width+"*"+height +` is almost definitely not what he wants, and changing the handler binding isn't going to fix the issue described.

Comment: But now you're going to be back to the same problem. The image won't be loaded until a click happens. Put the image creation back outside the handler, and just get its `width` and `height` inside.

Answer (score -1):

Your missing a semi colon on line 4.

```
img.src = urlInput
```

Comment: That doesn't matter. JS has automatic semicolon insertion.

Comment: Its browser dependant, always good practice to have a semi colon at the end of a line.

Comment: It's not browser dependent. It's described in detail in ECMAScript.